Running a bash script as a specific user iwth GUI -> Authentication required
so lately I have been cooking up this script of mine which starts google chrome in a kiosk mode with a specific window open. Pretty simple right?
This and the few neat extra features work really well when I log in manually. But I want it automated.
So I enabled the automatic Login option in the Settings (Debian 12), restarted and tried to run it. But then it asks for authentication and I have to manually type the password in. Can I somehow get rid of this?
I didn't find a working solution.
So I thought that a crontab may be the solution as I have to use it anyways to start the script after every reboot. But it didnn't work. It didn't open a visible Window. It gave me a Chrome error which stated something like "use --no-sandbox" and an error that it "Can't open Display (null)".
Does anyone have an idea what could fix this?
#!/bin/bash

export DISPLAY=:0
KIOSKURL="linkwasremovedbecauseprivacy"
expected_windowname="windowtitle - Google Chrome"

# Startet den Chrome Browser
run_chrome() {
    google-chrome --chrome-frame --kiosk "$KIOSKURL" &
    PID=$!
    sleep 5
    wmctrl -a "$expected_windowname"
    sleep 10
}

# Überprüft, ob Chrome überhaupt geöffnet ist.
is_chrome_running() {
    if pgrep -x "chrome" > /dev/null; then
        echo "Chrome is geöffnet"
        chromerunning="TRUE"
    else
        echo "Chrome ist nicht geöffnet"
        chromerunning="FALSE"
    fi
}


run_chrome
is_chrome_running

# Gleicht den Namen des aktiven Chrome-Fensters mit dem "$expected_windowname" ab
check_active_windowname() {
    active_windowname=$(xdotool search --name "Google Chrome" getwindowname)
    if [ "$active_windowname" != "$expected_windowname" ]; then
        echo "URL mismatch! Erwartet: $expected_windowname, Aktuell: $active_windowname"
        kill $PID
        run_chrome
    fi
    if [ "$active_windowname" = "$expected_windowname" ]; then
        echo "URL match! Offenes Fenster: $expected_windowname"
    fi
}

# Ermittelt die aktuelle Uhrzeit in folgendem Format: HHMMSS
time=$(date +"%H%M%S")

# Schleife, welche sich alle 30 Sekunden wiederholt
while true && [ "$time" -lt "135930" ]; do

    # Wenn Chrome geöffnet ist, wird das geöffnete Fenster überprüft (siehe oben) und anschließend wird nochmal geprüft, ob Chrome geöffnet ist
    if [ "$chromerunning" = "TRUE" ]; then
        check_active_windowname
        is_chrome_running

    # Wenn Chrome nicht geöffnet ist, wird es gestartet und anschließend wird überprüft, ob Chrome geöffnet wurde.
    elif [ "$chromerunning" = "FALSE" ]; then
        run_chrome
        is_chrome_running

    # Wenn Chrome weder geöffnet, noch geschlossen ist, ergibt das einen kritischen Fehler
    else
        echo "Kritischer Fehler"
    fi
    sleep 30
    check_active_windowname
    wmctrl -a "$expected_windowname"
    time=$(date +"%H%M%S")
    echo "Script erfolgreich durlaufen um $time"
done
if [ "$time" -gt "135930" ]; then
    kill $PID
    echo "Es ist später als 13:59:30. Ab jetzt wird der Firefox-Browser gestartet"
    exit
fi

